# Android - Setting Pressed State and Border on a TextView - Only one Background

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

I have 3 TextViews stacked vertically in a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:text="Item1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:text="Item2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:text="Item3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I could apply a drawable to the background attribute to render a Border

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/pale_grey" />
            <padding android:left="24dp" android:right="24dp" 
                       android:top="12dp" android:bottom="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I could also apply a selector, via a drawable, to the background property so that the TextView changed color depending on states such as Pressed. However there is only one background attribute.

I do not believe i can apply the **<shape>** xml and the **<selector>** xml within the same drawable. Therefore do I need to wrap a single layout element around each TextView just so can apply another background?

It looks like google solves this by encompassing border, padding and background colour into one drawable patch-9 image. I was hoping I didn't need to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the selector set the state pressed and unpressed with your XML's that render the border

Example:

```
<selector     xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/border_unpressed" android:state_pressed="false"/> 
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/border_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/border_unpressed" />

</selector>
```

Note:
Make sure to set the TextView attribute android:clickable="true"

Comment: Are you saying that I incorporate the background color setting and the border shape and stroke setting in the one drawable? That sounds so obvious now. wrt to :clickable ye i was just cutting most of the xml  out to make the question smaller

Comment: Yes but you should create two xml drawables, one with the pressed effect and one with the unpressed effect. And please if this works for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: I've been dragged off onto something else but as soon as I get back to this I will try it and definitely come back to accept

Comment: Sherif. Done works, just wish Android wasn't not making me create multiple files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp">
            </corners>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#187cb6"
                android:endColor="#187cb6"
                android:angle="270"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
            <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```