# Does Android TextView support state_pressed state?

Tags: android, textview, statelistdrawable

The real quest is to have a custom ButtonBar(as below) in Android with TextViews acts as buttons and each should reflect their state, pressed/selected.

[image]

The TextView is set with the following background for different states to reflect. What all states supported by Android TextView? Say e.g., if it supports states like pressed/selected, how to update the TextView from XML/Code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16.5dp" />
            <size android:width="168dp" android:height="34dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:color="#000000" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="16.5dp" />
            <size android:width="168dp" android:height="34dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

TextView code snippet below for reference

```xml
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tv_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onTvClicked()}"
            android:text="@string/TVTEXT"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/something"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/otherthing"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I think this should help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891459/android-setting-pressed-state-and-border-on-a-textview-only-one-background

Comment: Thanks, but the clicked=true in TextView & android:state_pressed="true" in drawable reflects the color change on click not persists. Is there anyway to keep the color change on selection as in the ButtonBar?